# Black screen when tab bar is selected

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am having a problem with a black screen when i switch to the "friends" tab on my application. This does happen because of my friendsviewcontroller. I know this because I removed the link to the viewcontroller and it presented me with the normal screen. Hope someone can see what I have done wrong

FriendsViewController:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit


class FriendsViewController: UITabBarController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{



@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var friendTypeSwitch: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var friendSearchBar: UITextField!
var user:User = User()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("Friends tab")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("view did appear")
}






func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 30
}
//What to do with tableview
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "friendCell", for: indexPath) as! friendsCustomCell
    user.username = "kulgut123"

    cell.friendName.text = user.username



            return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}



}

class friendsCustomCell: UITableViewCell{

@IBOutlet weak var friendImg: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var friendName: UILabel!

}
```

Comment: Can you provide info about the way you connect your `FriendsViewController ` to the corresponding tab?

Comment: I think the problem is because you subclass from `UITabBarController `. I think you want to subclass from `UIViewController`

Comment: Yes, I have connected it by ctrl dragging from the yellow square in the tab bar controller straight to the friendsView. Is there maybe a better way to implement it?

Comment: You were right @ronatory

Comment: Nice, so it works now?

Comment: yes sir! +1234567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ronatory suggests, you should subclass FriendsViewController from UIViewController instead of UITabBarController.

```
class FriendsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
      //type your code here
}
```